# Как раздать интернет OpenVpn в другую сеть?

Tags: openvpn

Есть два ПК в разных сетях. Мне нужно с первого, выходить в интернет, через сеть второго.

ПК_1 179.98.33.15

ПК_2 178.76.30.44

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при проверке текущего ip в интернете первого компьютера, я выдел ip второго.

Правильно ли я понимаю. Я создаю виртуальную сеть и вижу удаленный ПК как локальный, с помощью туннеля и виртуальной сетевой карты?
Как можно будет переключаться между сервисами?